# How to access .NET 7 WPF controls default templates?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-7.0

In .Net Framework I could use blend or visual studio using menu `Edit Template - Create a Copy` to have complete XAML of a default style.

Today I tried to have a `Button` default style in .NET 7 WPF app in VS2022 and the `Create a Copy` option is grayed-out.

Where am I supposed to get it from now?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-7.0

Comment: that is for .Net Framework. how can you be sure those apply on .Net 7 1:1 ?

Comment: I did click .Net 7... under the menu you have the option for .Net 7 and .Net 6

Comment: If you select any of it - you will see that it say there is no document for 6/7 and that is the best version they have (4.x)

Comment: Did you select the control in the designer, right click and look at the context menu? Worked for me when I tried it a couple of days ago with a .net 7 app.

Comment: yes. tried both VS and Blend on a simple Button - "Edit a Copy" is grayed out

Comment: solved - it was WPF app created from Devexpress template and there Edit a Copy is not available (presumably due to their theming mechanism, I suspect they generate control templates in runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button to your designer and then right click the button for the context menu. Then selecting Edit Template -> Edit a Copy will show a dialog that will allow you to save the ControlTemplate either locally or in App.xaml

[image: ContextMenu]

Comment: I found out why I dont have `Edit a Copy` available - it is specific to the Devexpress - I used their VS project template to create the test app. In "normal" WPF it works fine.

Comment: Using third party controls like Devexpress, Syncfusion or Telerik has always caused me nothing but headaches, best wishes with your project